# Can non-sudo user add systemd units?

Tags: rabbitmq, ubuntu-16.04, backgroundworker, systemd, supervisord

I have a pair of application with a lot of crons and daemon workers (rabbitmq consumers).

I want to give permissions to some users to deploy apps, but not administrative permissions. The problem is: daemon workers are managed by systemd units and changing of systemd units requires root access.

How can we solve this solution? I know that I can use supervisord instead of systemd, but it's a last resort and I really don't want to switch to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't allow a user to start a service as root (or as any other user), but users can start units in with `user bus`, just place them in `~/.config/systemd/user/` (create the dir if does not exist), then you can

```
  systemctl --user daemon-reload
  systemctl --user start <your service>.service
  systemctl --user status <your service>.service
```

Also user can start "*transient units*" as **themself**, using the same user-bus, and then manage them (start, stop, kill, restart, etc) as regular units.

*Transient units* are exactly like regular units but cant survive server restarts...

you start them with `systemd-run --user` and then manage them with `systemctl --user`

example

```
$ systemd-run --user /bin/sleep 300
Running as unit: run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service

$ systemctl --user status run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service
● run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service - /bin/sleep 300
    Loaded: loaded (/run/user/1000/systemd/transient/run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5
    Transient: yes
    Active: active (running) since Thu 2018-03-15 20:31:52 PDT; 15s ago
    Main PID: 21095 (sleep)
    CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30
           └─21095 /bin/sleep 300

$ systemctl --user stop run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service

$ systemctl --user status run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service
Unit run-r6545f2e54ffc4f30b15f5dcabb280e5a.service could not be found.
```

Note on older systemd, make sure the dbus is running on your system, and accessible for the user, in general make sure you have `DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS` and `XDG_RUNTIME_DIR` environment variable set.

Comment: How can I fix this error? $ systemd-run --user /bin/sleep 300
Failed to start transient service unit: Process org.freedesktop.systemd1 exited with status 1

Comment: i would ask the following questions: 1) what version of systemd are you using?, 2) are you runing "systemd-run --user" as a regular user or root (it should be regular user)? and 3) does /bin/sleep exist in your system, or is it another path?

Comment: 1) default from latest LTS ubuntu (2) regular, (3) sure

Comment: i edited my answer due some new info i stumble by reading documentation. basically you can create units and run them in the user bus by placing them in ` ~/.config/systemd/user`

Comment: I restarted my testing computer, and user units started to work. But how can I enable this feature right after `loginctl enable-linger <user>` command?